# How to Implement Mongoose blacklist Schema?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I Have Two Schema, `Person` and `Message`, How to Implement Mongoose blacklist Schema?

I Mean One user can block another user when he does not like his message.
Should I need a new Schema for better performance?
Please give an example

**Person:**

```
const personSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number, 
  tok: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  name: String,
  pwd: String,
  gender: String,
});
```

**Message:**

```
const messageSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {type: Number, ref: 'Person'},
  text: String,
  voice: String,
  senderId: Number,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an array of references to users that should be blacklisted.

`const personSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number, 
    tok: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    name: String,
    pwd: String,
    gender: String,
    blacklist: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'user' // same as 1st arg to mongoose.model()
    }]
});`

Comment: Do I need to  `ref: 'user'` ? Because I have just person and message Schema

Comment: that just tells mongoose which collection to associate the objectId with. unless you'd rather just store the entire blackListed user's document in there. That decision ultimately boils down to how many users you think people will block and what level of duplication you're willing to live with. The ref can point to the same collection that personSchemas get stored in, the only thing that will get stored in the actual db is an objectId.